# replace the brush with list of images?

Tags: c#

i have seen this [article](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/6f2YNr) and i wonder if i can replace the brush with list of images?

here's the code to create an `AVI` file from brush :

```
        private void buttonCreateVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;

        VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();
        writer.Open("code-bude_test_video.avi", width, height, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 100000);

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, width, height);
        Brush[] brushList = new Brush[] { Brushes.Green, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Yellow, Brushes.Pink, Brushes.LimeGreen };

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            g.FillRectangle(brushList[i % 5], (i % width) * 2, (i % height) * 0.5f, i % 30, i % 30);
            g.FillRectangle(brushList[i % 5], (i % width) * 2, (i % height) * 2, i % 30, i % 30);
            g.FillRectangle(brushList[i % 5], (i % width) * 0.5f, (i % height) * 2, i % 30, i % 30);
            g.Save();
            writer.WriteVideoFrame(image);
        }

        writer.Close();
    }
```

and here is my list:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        NumericComparer ns = new NumericComparer();
        string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.Jpeg");
        ns = new NumericComparer(); // new object
        Array.Sort(array1, ns);

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string name in array1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(name);
        }
    }
}
```

all i need is to add images from folder and save them in `.avi` video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    var frame = new Bitmap(name);
    g.DrawImage(frame, 0, 0, width, height);
    writer.WriteVideoFrame(image);
}
```