# How to convert thousands of images to one small sized video

Tags: c#, image, video

I want to convert thousands of images to one video with small size, I did asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376630/replace-the-brush-with-list-of-images) and I get out of memory message with few hundred of images!, so I am wondering what coding technique could work for me to convert them to be (for the user) a push of a button and easy to understand by me?

Comment: You can look this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library

Comment: nice but even it's title `A Simple C# Wrapper` i can't find it easy!,